# Why does my button not receive data from my 2 text field?

Tags: html, post

Why wont my button receive any data from my text fields?

Every time I press ok it only posts the word "Submit".

This is my code.

```
 <div class="well">
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2"> 
                <div class="input-holder">
                    <input type="text" class="form-input" id="membernumber" name="membernumber" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Medlems. Nr.*" value="">
                </div>

        </div>

        <div class="span2"> 
                <div class="input-holder">
                    <input type="text" class="form-input" id="subtotal" name="subtotal" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Beløb.*" value="">
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span2"> 
                <div class="input-holder">
                    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                    <input type="submit" name="update" value="update">
                        </form>
                 </div>
        </div>
</div>

</div>
```

This is how i recieved it.

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    // Escape any html characters
    echo htmlentities($_POST['update']);
}
```

Comment: Your 2 text fields are outside the form tag,so you can access them, because they are not submitted on click of submit button

Answer (score 0):

you dont include the other input fields in the `<form>`. It must look like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
    <input name="foo">
    <input name="bar">
    <button type="submit">foo</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your code to work, it must look something like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<div class="well">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2"> 
            <div class="input-holder">
                <input type="text" class="form-input" id="membernumber" name="membernumber" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Medlems. Nr.*" value="">
            </div>

    </div>

    <div class="span2"> 
            <div class="input-holder">
                <input type="text" class="form-input" id="subtotal" name="subtotal" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Beløb.*" value="">
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span2"> 
            <div class="input-holder">

                <input type="submit" name="update" value="update">

             </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</form>
```

Let me know if this doesn't work. If you are submitting to the same page - generally - you can leave the action blank e.g.

```
action = ''
```

EDIT: This is how you retrieve your POST variables. Look at what you are doing - you are checking whether the variable with an index of "update" is set, then outputting it.

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
   // Escape any html characters
   echo htmlentities($_POST['update']);
}
```

This will always echo the contents of this input:

```
<input type="submit" name="update" value="update">
```

NOTE: THE NAME = "update". To output membernumber and subtotal, you would need to access those respectivly:

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

   // Escape any html characters
   echo htmlentities($_POST['update']); // the submit button - will always output the value 'submit'
   echo htmlentities($_POST['membernumber']); // the membernumber text box
   echo htmlentities($_POST['subtotal']); // the subtotal text box

}
```

Comment: Remember, by putting input's within a form tag and submitting it via POST - you will receive a $_POST array - which is the same as every other array in the world. If you create a textbox with the name "thisismytextbox" - when submitted, this can be accessed by $_POST['thisismytextbox'];